# (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory in Yocto

Tags: intel, yocto, xorg, xserver

I have built `core-image-sato` for my device but device **fails to boot into GUI mode**.

When I looked at `Xorg.0.log` file, found that Xserver is unable to find device node(`/dev/dri/card0`).

This question is asked in multiple forums and people could resolve them also but none of the solution seem to work for me in my device running yocto `warrior` branch with `4.19.62-intel-pk-standard` kernel.

> I would be really tankful if you could help me to get Xserver working?

Attaching `Xorg.0.log` for reference,

```
[   311.723] 
X.Org X Server 1.20.4
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[   311.723] Build Operating System: Linux 5.3.0-40-generic x86_64 
[   311.723] Current Operating System: Linux panther1 4.19.62-intel-pk-standard #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Mar 18 02:52:04 UTC 2020 x86_64
[   311.723] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz label=boot root=PARTUUID=8284c79f-02 rootwait rootfstype=ext4 video=vesafb vga=0x318 console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200n8
[   311.723] Build Date: 17 March 2020  08:37:43AM
[   311.723]  
[   311.723] Current version of pixman: 0.38.0
[   311.723]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[   311.723] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[   311.723] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Wed Mar 18 07:31:59 2020
[   311.724] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[   311.724] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[   311.724] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[   311.724] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[   311.724] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[   311.725] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[   311.725] (==) Automatically adding devices
[   311.725] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[   311.725] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[   311.725] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[   311.725] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc/" does not exist.
[   311.725]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   311.725] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/TTF/" does not exist.
[   311.725]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   311.726] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/OTF/" does not exist.
[   311.726]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   311.726] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1/" does not exist.
[   311.726]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   311.726] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[   311.726]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   311.726] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[   311.726]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   311.726] (==) FontPath set to:

[   311.726] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib64/xorg/modules"
[   311.726] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[   311.726] (II) Loader magic: 0x56511022cd00
[   311.726] (II) Module ABI versions:
[   311.726]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[   311.726]    X.Org Video Driver: 24.0
[   311.726]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.1
[   311.726]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[   311.727] (--) using VT number 2

[   311.727] (II) systemd-logind: logind integration requires -keeptty and -keeptty was not provided, disabling logind integration
[   311.735] (--) PCI:*(0@0:2:0) 8086:0be2:8086:7270 rev 11, Mem @ 0x40200000/1048576, I/O @ 0x000040d0/8, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[   311.736] (II) Open ACPI successful (/var/run/acpid.socket)
[   311.736] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[   311.736] (II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[   311.745] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   311.745]    compiled for 1.20.4, module version = 1.0.0
[   311.745]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0
[   311.745] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 0
[   311.745] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 1
[   311.745] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 2
[   311.745] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[   311.745] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[   311.745] (II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[   311.745] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   311.745]    compiled for 1.20.4, module version = 1.20.4
[   311.745]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   311.745]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0
[   311.745] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[   311.746] (II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[   311.746] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   311.746]    compiled for 1.20.4, module version = 0.5.0
[   311.746]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   311.746]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0
[   311.746] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[   311.746] (II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[   311.747] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   311.747]    compiled for 1.20.4, module version = 2.4.0
[   311.747]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   311.747]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0
[   311.747] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[   311.747] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[   311.747] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[   311.772] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[   311.772] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[   311.772] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[   311.772] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[   311.772] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[   311.772] (II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[   311.773] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   311.773]    compiled for 1.20.4, module version = 0.0.2
[   311.773]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0
[   311.773] (EE) Unable to find a valid framebuffer device
[   311.773] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[   311.773] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[   311.773] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[   311.773] (II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[   311.774] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   311.774]    compiled for 1.20.4, module version = 0.0.2
[   311.774]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0
[   311.774] (II) FBDEV(2): using default device
[   311.774] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[   311.774] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[   311.774] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[   311.774] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[   311.774] (II) UnloadSubModule: "fbdevhw"
[   311.774] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[   311.774] (EE) Cannot run in framebuffer mode. Please specify busIDs        for all framebuffer devices
[   311.774] (EE) Cannot run in framebuffer mode. Please specify busIDs        for all framebuffer devices
[   311.774] (EE) 
[   311.774] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[   311.774] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[   311.774] (EE) 
[   311.824] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```